# How can we get the user traffic of the Stack Overflow website?

Tags: discussion, research

I am researching on students from different locations/countries on Stack Overflow. How does SO help them? So I need user traffic data on the Stack Overflow website. Something similar to [this blog from 2017](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/02/15/how-do-students-use-stack-overflow/) about how students use SO.

I cannot find anything in the SO dumps on Stack Exchange. I tried Quantcast, but it says I am not authorized to see this. This is not only about Quantcast only, but any other way I can get this information apart from Quantcast.

Comment: Would any of the analytics data available to 25k+ reputation users (https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/site-analytics) help with this?

Answer (score 14):

For reasons of privacy this data is not publicly available.

If you need this data as part of an academic research goal, your best bet is contacting Stack Exchange directly ([Contact form](https://stackoverflow.com/company/contact) can be found in the footer).

Make sure you have a decent research plan, what your hypothesis is and where you need the data for, among other things.

If Stack Exchange decide they want to work with you, be prepared to sign an [Non-Disclosure Agreement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-disclosure_agreement) (NDA). No one here wants to find their [Personal Identifiable Information](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/privacy-policy) (PII) in some research dataset posted on [PasteBin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pastebin).

To quote [Adam Lear](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/258798)

> ... We love research, but when in doubt, we err on the side of more aggressively protecting user rights, even at the cost of the pursuit of knowledge

Comment: Just leaving a comment here to confirm that this answer provides the guidance staff would have provided — use the contact form and our data team will evaluate your request.